MariaDb initialization with docker-compose
I am trying to set up MariaDB in docker-compose. When initializes, it should have the following:

root allowed to connect from anywhere (%)
a specific DB created
a specific user created
the user granted all access on that db.

I made a script for that, which is mounted as a volume in the container description.
--init-file parameter sounds good, but it can't do the job as the mysql database itself is not created yet at that point at the first run. Hence the mysqld startup fails with:
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Is there any way to run some script at startup but after everything is initialized, or any other way to create these artifacts at the first run?

https://serverfault.com/questions/796762/creating-a-docker-mysql-container-with-a-prepared-database-scheme could help

Does this answer your question? How can I initialize a MySQL database with schema in a Docker container?

@NicoHaase MariaDB's container is a lot more feature complete than a 12 year old mysql one. Don't forget to include official current documentation in the search to provide quick answers.

Per the reference, mounting a directory with your init file in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and ensuring that the file as an extension that is recognised will achieve initializing your data directory.
After the data directory is initialized, the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d contents are ignored.
